# Почему на Github пушатся файлы из gitignore?

Tags: git, github

Такая ситуация:
создал репозиторий на локалке с настройками в gitignore:

```
# Created by https://www.gitignore.io/api/nuxtjs
# Edit at https://www.gitignore.io/?templates=nuxtjs

### Nuxtjs ###
# dependencies
node_modules

# logs
npm-debug.log

# Nuxt build
.nuxt

# Nuxt generate
dist

# My IDE
.idea

# End of https://www.gitignore.io/api/nuxtjs
```

Далее запушил на пустой удаленный новосозданный приватный репозиторий свой локальный проект:

```
git push -u origin master
```

В итоге получил вот такие файлы на гитхабе:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос:
Почему запушились на гитхаб файлы который были в списке gitignore?
(Что я упустил из виду и какие могут быть варианты?)

Comment: потому что они были добавлены в коммит. gitignore не препятствует файлу быть закомиченным. Он только не показывает его в списке измененных файлов. Но всегда остается возможность добавить файл ручками. В Вашем случае скорее всего эти файлы были закоммичены раньше, а потом уже был создан .gitignore

Comment: Я полагаю так и было - а что можно сделать что бы эти игнорируемые файлы не пушились на гибхаб и является ли такая практика нормальной?

Comment: да, можно.  И это штатная практика. Только нужно делать все в правильной последовательности - вначале gitignore, потом аккуратно коммитить.

Comment: *а что можно сделать что бы эти игнорируемые файлы не пушились* — очевидно же: начните с того, что перестаньте коммитить изменения в этих файлах.

Comment: ok. я так и понял - вопрос уже решен.